# Failed to locate library: liblwjgl_opengl.so

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to learn opengl rendering, and for this I am trying to familiarise myself with lwjgl. At the moment I have a program with creates a GLFW window, and I've already tested that works, and it contains the line `GL.CreateCapabilities();`

For some reason this results in the error `Failed to locate library: liblwjgl_opengl.so`
I think this has something to do with natives, but there is no opengl native in the archive I downloaded from the lwjgl website (I had the "everything" preset). Other answers involve added .so files (I'm on linux) but I don't have any of them, just some jars with "natives" in their name, and there is no opengl native.

EDIT: this is not like the suggested duplicate answer 1.) there is not .so native for opengl and 2.) the other native jars are already in the classpath.

Comment: The "opengl native" should be on your OS already.  Which OS and IDE are you using?  Or if not an IDE then what's your build environment?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 17.10 using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you could try looking at https://www.lwjgl.org/browse to find the files
for example https://build.lwjgl.org/release/latest/linux/x64/liblwjgl_opengl.so

p.s. the only natives i use on windows are:
`lwjgl.dll` / `lwjgl64.dll` and `OpenAL32.dll` / `OpenAL64.dll`

Comment: I downloaded the file and added it to classpath to no avail.

Comment: have you used lwjgl in the past? or at least on linux? if you are following a tutorial, i would suggest also seeing if you can get some help from the writer/uploader. have you tried using different lwjgl versions also? if you install minecraft btw, you can go in .minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1 and get the natives. and also the libs. hope that helps